# Fail to display image using phonegap on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, image

Guys I'm currently working on the development of an app using phonegap on eclipse, but I hit a bump when I'm trying to display an image, I have tried thousands of ways to modify my code, but the image just cannot be displayed, but when I browsed through others' coding, I didn't see much difference, will really appreciate it if you guys could help me figure out.

My code for a certain page is shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>About Us</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href = "css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" type="text/css" charset = "utf-8" src = "cordova-2.3.0.js">

<script src = "js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js." type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8" src = "cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    function onBodyLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", PhonegapLoaded, false);
    }
    function PhonegapLoaded(){
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Back Button Pressed");
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        }, true);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload = "onBodyLoad();">
<div data-role = "page" id = "aboutus">
<a href="index.html" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
<div class="ui-btn-active" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<h1>ABOUT US</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<img src="images/icon.png">
</div>


<div data-role="footer">
<h4>Footer</h4>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use this route:

```
<img src="images/icon.png">
```

Comment: The bad path of image does not cause this error. Remove onload attribute from body

Comment: onload attributes like?